# Best practice to track websocket connections in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, websocket, synchronized

Suppose my game server can host 1M users, meaning I need to keep track of 1M websocket connections, what is the suitable data structure (or collection) for doing that? And what is the strategy to handle synchronization issue?

1. synchronize on the collection when adding/removing/iterating the collection. - It might hit bad performance issue,
2. no synchronization, It might have trouble with iterating the sockets (e.g. sending out broadcast messages) when new connection is added or existing connection is removed (because user go offline)
3. use `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, it increases the GC load when user online/offline frequently

Answer (score 1):

Use `readLock` when iterate read data, use `writeLock` when write data. That's how [t-io](https://git.oschina.net/tywo45/t-io) is played.